# How to make dll in visual c++ , i want to interact it with C#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, interface

i wrote my program in `visual studio 10` with c++ but now i want to make `dll` of it to use it with interface of visual c# , i am using command line argument in my program for input

I saw tutorial from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) , but my code is not as small as there , i have 1000 of lines , so i can not wrote like this

```
static __declspec(dllexport) double Add(double a, double b);
```

for every line and am also using `opencv` library in it so whats the other way to create the dll of c++ program , or how can i simply use it with c# interface .

Comment: Every function you want exported must be marked `__declspec(dllexport)`. Change your output file type to DLL. Then look into P/Invoke for calling it from C#.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart My libraries like `opencv` which i add manually in my program , automatically transfer to dll or do i need to configure it again in my c# project

Comment: As long as the DLL is properly linked to OpenCV (statically or dynamically), your C# program shouldn't have to know anything about it.

Comment: i have a .exe file of my program , which is working with `cmd` , can i use `.exe` instead of `dll` , for the same purpose (just for interface , and interface is only for input and output)

Comment: This is only easy if you wrote your code in C++/CLI or created a COM component with a type library.  Sure, using __declspec(dllexport) and building a DLL works but it has to be called with pinvoke in the C# program.  Which requires writing [DllImport] declarations in C#, no help at all from the IDE.  And that only works on simple C-style functions, not C++ classes.  Look at C++/CLI to get ahead.

Comment: @HansPassant You want to say that i need to open the project in class library and than change the properties of project to CLI ? and convert the code in library ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways in which two programs can interact.

Even with `__declspec (dllexport)`, it's not to be added to each and every line of your program. Rather, you need to add it to the "exported functions". So, the first thing you need to do is to **create a list of functions that you want to export from your C++ program**. You might get better responses here if you provide a bit of more insight into what your interface will look like.

Beyond DLL's, there are other ways through which programs can interact. Even file I/O is a possibility, when there is no other way feasible, where one program writes to a file as an input and the other program reads it.

Comment: My input is image in the form of MAT which belongs to opencv , and my output is in the form of text file , i tried the way of showing output of text file on interface , it works ,but showing error for input, but i want to know do i need to configure opencv for c# too , even if i have .exe of the whole program

Comment: What actually i am doing is using my c++ code exe file in the refrence of c# project and use process.start with it , but it gives me error for my project of opencv , but when i run the same program with cmd it works , and when i run the simple program of c++ and include its exe in c# it works with process.start and interface